# Show Empty data if div with specific text is not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have element like this :

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="filter()" id="filter_data">

<div id="body">
  <div class="child"> Text 1 </div>
  <div class="child"> Text 2 </div>
  <div class="child"> Text 1 </div>
</div>
```

I want to search the div text by input value.

I can search the data but.. how to show "data Not found" inside div body, if all child div is not have any data like input value.

**[This my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0k8ustrv/)**.

Comment: what you really need to achieve

Comment: how show "data Not found" inside div body, if all child div is not have any data like input value

Comment: create another `div` with content as `data Not found` in `body` and make it hidden by default then show that div if no match occur.

Comment: @AvistaKautsar **To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0k8ustrv/11/)**.

You could add an increment a variable (`result` in my example) to know if there's any data found or not then `show/hide` the message :

```
if( result === 0 ){
    $('.empty_div').removeClass('hide');
}else{
    $('.empty_div').addClass('hide');
}
```

```js
function filter() {
  var value = $('#filter_data').val();
  var div_class = $('#body').find(".child");
  var result = 0;

  div_class.hide();
  div_class.each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(value.toUpperCase()) != -1) {
      $(this).show();
      result++;
    }
  });

  if (result === 0) {
    $('.empty_div').removeClass('hide');
  } else {
    $('.empty_div').addClass('hide');
  }
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" onkeyup="filter()" id="filter_data">
<div id="body">
  <div class="child"> Text 1 </div>
  <div class="child"> Text 2 </div>
  <div class="child"> Text 1 </div>
  <div class="empty_div hide">No Data Found</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If any answer helps you @Avista vote it up, and if the answer is what you're looking for mark it as **[the correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** for the future readers

Answer (score 1):

Add one more div and fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thecreativedev/0k8ustrv/62/

**JS**

```
function filter() {
    var value = $('#filter_data').val();
    var div_class = $('#body').find(".child");
    $('.nomatched').html('').hide();
    div_class.hide();
    var i =0;
    div_class.each(function() {     
       if ($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(value.toUpperCase()) != -1) {
          $(this).show();
          ++i;
        }
    });
    if(i == 0){
        $('.nomatched').html('No matched data Found').show();
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="filter()" id="filter_data">
<div id="body">
  <div class="child"> Text 1 </div>
  <div class="child"> Text 2 </div>
  <div class="child"> Text 1 </div>
  <div class="nomatched" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: when you type text2 it shows not matched data found as well